# link wrapping not working on iPad

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a link whose text is wrapped on my Android cellphone and Computer but not on the iPad. I used Chrome and Safari on the iPad but neither of them wrapped the text.

This is my HTML/CSS:

```
<a href="#" id="link1" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" style="word-spacing: normal; float: left; text-align: left; font-size: 75%;">aaaaa bbbbb ccccc ddddd eeeee fffff</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css should be white-space: normal not word-spacing. Also, remove the float: left rule:

```
<a href="#" id="link1" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" style="white-space: normal;  text-align: left; font-size: 75%;">aaaaa bbbbb ccccc ddddd eeeee fffff</a>
```